# Питон path в переменной среде, укажите пожалуйста путь в виндовс 8

Tags: python, path

Мне нужно чтобы питон выводился через командную строку при команде python но не выводится,
и я случайно удалил путь в переменной среде для Path можете подсказать путь? или решения этой проблемы питон 3,8,2

Comment: Папка, где лежит файл python.exe.

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: Значит неправильно добавил. Закрой-открой командную строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 - нагуглить как этот процесс можно сделать самому [How do I add Python to the Windows PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)
.

Вариант 2 - штатно удалить Python, а затем (как ни странно может показаться) опять его инсталлировать. В процессе должна появиться менюшка, где проставляется галка (чек-бокс) этот самый PATH прописать автоматически.